# Number of unique items in a list in Python

Tags: python

If I have a set of items in a list say:

```
MyList = ["a", "b", "c", "c", "b"]
```

And I want to get the count of the total number of unique items (in this case 3)

I figure it needs to be some variant on `len(myList)` but I'm not sure how to eliminate the duplicates?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer the part about it being duplicate... it's true, but for some reason I didn't find it with a google search, and I think my version of the question is a bit clearer (but I'm ok with this being deleted if need be as I got my answer)

Answer (score 6):

You can convert your list to a `set` which is guaranteed to have unique items:

```
MyList = ["a", "b", "c", "c", "b"]
print len(set(MyList))
```

result:

```
3
```

Comment: perfect thanks - worked exactly as I needed it to!